# Passing value through PHP expression to make a float

Tags: php

What will pass through this statement?

```
$a=($_POST['a']*1337)+1.7;

$a=!preg_match('/[^0-9]/',''.$a)?(int)round($a)-33:1337;
```

My goal is to make $a == 'float';

Comment: First line evaluation is assigned to nowhere. And the whole question is obscure.

Comment: My bad, sorry, fix'd now

Answer (score 1):

```
$a=!preg_match('/[^0-9]/',''.$a)?(int)round($a)-33:1337;
```

`$a` is set to the ternary result of the negation of the return of `preg_match()`, which tests the regex `[^0-9]` on `$a` concatenated with an empty string. The responses are `round()`ed and cast to integer `$a` - `33` or `1337`.

I'd say this code could be written much nicer as...

```
$a = preg_match('/\D/', (string) $a) ? 1337 : (int) round($a) - 33;
```

Answer (score 0):

if your goal is to make $a float then just try casting:

```
$a = (float) $_POST['a'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Better Way (**KISS** Theory)

```
$a=$_POST['a']*1337+1.7;
if(preg_match('/\D/', (string) $a))
 $a = 1337 
else
 $a = (int) round($a) - 33;
```

**Note:** instead of `(int) round($a)` you should use either `floor` or `ceil`